# toupper function in C

Tags: c, function, toupper

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* strcaps(char* s)
{
        while (*s != '\0')
        {
                toupper(*s);
                s++;
        }
        return s;
}
```

.

```
int main()
{
        char makeCap[100];
        printf("Type what you want to capitalize: ");
        fgets(makeCap, 100, stdin);
        strcaps(makeCap);
        return 0;
}
```

this program compiles just fine, but when I run it, it doesn't output anything. what am i missing here?

Comment: To begin with, there is no command for showing the result in the output. And the `toupper` return value is ignored...

Comment: the command for showing result in output is the return, right? how is topupper ignored, nvm i got java in the mind

Comment: Please tag your question *either* with C *or* with Java. Not both. Here you ask a *C* question …

Comment: return doesn't print anything on it's own, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing anything!

Print the return value of `toupper()`.

```
        printf("%c",toupper(*s));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't print anything, so of course it won't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* strcaps(char* s){
    char *p;
    for (p=s; *p; ++p)
        *p = toupper(*p);//maybe you want to change the original
    return s;//your cord : return address point to '\0'
}
...
//main
printf("%s", strcaps(makeCap));
```